# Values are not incrementing/decrementing in JavaScript cart file

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce, cart

I tried a lot of things, even watching a YouTube video, but that did not help. I am new to programming. If JavaScript gets called, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group number-spinner"> 
<button id="phone-minus" class="btn-default">
<i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></button>
<input type="number" id="phone-number" value="0" class="form-control text-center" value="1">
<button id="phone-plus" class="btn btn-default">
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button> </div>
```

In the JavaScript file, I thought about using the increment function, but still work as expected. Is there a better way to go around this?

JavaScript file:

```
    function updateProductNumber(product, price, isIncreasing) {
    const productNumber = document.getElementById(product + '- 
    number');
    let productValue = parseInt(productNumber.value);
    if (isIncreasing) {
        productValue = productValue + 1;
    } else if (productValue > 0) {
        productValue = productValue - 1;
    }
    productNumber.value = productValue;

    // Update product total
    const productTotal = document.getElementById(product + '-total');
    productTotal.innerText = productValue * price;
    calculateTotal();
    }

    function getElementValue(product) {
    const productInput = document.getElementById(product + '-number');
    const productValue = parseInt(productInput.value);
    return productValue;
    }

    function calculateTotal() {
    const phoneTotal = getElementValue('phone') * 1219;
    const caseTotal = getElementValue('case') * 59;
    const subTotal = phoneTotal + caseTotal;
    const tax = subTotal / 10;
    const totalPrice = subTotal + tax;

    // Update HTML elements
    document.getElementById('sub-total').innerHTML = subTotal;
    document.getElementById('tax-amount').innerHTML = tax;
    document.getElementById('total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice;
    }
    document.getElementById('case-plus').addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateProductNumber('case', 59, true);
    });
    document.getElementById('case-minus').addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateProductNumber('case', 59, false);
    });
    document.getElementById('phone-plus').addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateProductNumber('phone', 1219, true);
    });
    document.getElementById('phone-minus').addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateProductNumber('phone', 1219, false);
    });
```

Comment: Well i can see this will be a problem `document.getElementById(product + 'phone-number');` because when `updateProductNumber` is getting executed, then `document.getElementById(product + 'phone-number');` will be `document.getElementById('phonephone-number');`

Comment: I fixed that and still didn't work. Do i have to use the `onclick` function in my HTML tag?